# OpenCart: Add left column (contain categories etc) on Default page

Tags: themes, opencart

I want to add the 'Left Column' (categories etc) in the default page. I see that the left panel is exists on the product pages but missing from the default page. Please see the screen shot. Please suggest.

Comment: where is screenshot ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1 - Open the desired page in templates folder, example, content/information pages:

```
catalog\view\theme\default\template\information.tpl
```

2 - Add this line in the desired location:

```
<?php echo $column_left; ?>
```

If it fails, open the relevant MVC controller model of that code, example:

```
catalog\controller\information.php
```

Find `$this->children = array(`

Make sure the array contains the left panel, example:

```
$this->children = array(
    'common/column_left',
    'common/column_right',
    'common/content_top',
    'common/content_bottom',
    'common/footer',
    'common/header'
);
```

I hope you mean that information etc by default as the default, aka homepage, already has this: (`\catalog\view\theme\default\template\common\home.tpl`)

```
<?php echo $header; ?><?php echo $column_left; ?><?php echo $column_right; ?>
<div id="content"><?php echo $content_top; ?>
<h1 style="display: none;"><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
<?php echo $content_bottom; ?></div>
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm currently using the latest version of OpenCart (1.5.4.1). The View page (sitemap.tpl) contains - <?php echo $header; ?><?php echo $column_left; ?><?php echo $column_right; ?> - But no left or right panel is appearing. Please reply.

Comment: **Finally I solved this issue.** Go to the Extensions-> Modules -> Category -> Edit -> add module -> select "Home" from Layout drop-down list and select column left from the position list -> Click to SAVE. The category will appear in the default as well as home page.

Comment: There is actually a bug on Opencart 1.5.5.1 were the route is not correctly set for the sitemap.   I resolved it by going to admin panel, clicking System->Design->Layouts.  Then I clicked edit next to sitemap, and put in route information/sitemap.  Following that all the modules that I had assigned to the sitemap's left column appeared.   I don’t know if there is more robust soloution, but this seemed to work.